# What's mean of the API style that matching symbols?

Tags: json, api, url, github-api, restful-url

The special matching symbols in API url eg: `{?name}` , `{/other_user}`

How to deal with clients?

Why use it ?

Reference:

https://api.github.com/repos/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases

Example:

```
{
"upload_url": "https://uploads.github.com/repos/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases/1161957/assets{?name}", 
"id": 1161957,
"tag_name": "v1.6.0",
"author": {
    "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tianon/following{/other_user}",
    "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tianon/gists{/gist_id}",
    "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tianon/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
    "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tianon/subscriptions",
    "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tianon/orgs",
    "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tianon/repos",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tianon/events{/privacy}",
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're [URI templates](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570). The [GitHub API documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/#hypermedia) includes examples demonstrating the benefits of using these templates.

The GitHub API documentation uses the Ruby [uri_template](https://github.com/hannesg/uri_template) library in its examples. While uri_template is a Ruby gem, you can find URI template libraries for most popular programming languages. [This wiki](https://code.google.com/p/uri-templates/wiki/Implementations) (or a quick Google search) will probably help you find a URI template library for your language of choice.

Comment: What are the best benefits of URI templates?